# c# Regex quotes

Tags: c#, regex

How to parse string `"\"bcd ef\" a 'x y'"`, and catch all text between quotes `"`,`'` **and without them** with regular expressions? I tried pattern `"(\\\"|')(.*?)(\\\"|')`, but got only `"bcd ef"`, `'x y'`. Result should be:

1. `"bcd ef"`
2. `a`
3. `'x y'`

   ```
    string pattern   ="(\\\"|')(.*?)(\\\"|')";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
   ```

Comment: your result and description do not match, because `a` is _not_ `between quotes`.

Comment: corrected topic. i need parse all.

Comment: then how about simply 'Split'ting the string?

Comment: I try to learn Regex. Lern to parse different ways. Does Regex bad way for parsing?

Comment: learning about regexes is a good and neccessary thing. but the most important lesson is: only use it when you _really_ need it, and no other solution is practicable. because regexes are hard to understand, hard to maintain, and, when done wrong, can be absolute performance killers. for better understanding them, i can recommend https://regex101.com/, by the way

Answer (score 1):

Two options are string.Split() or Regex.Split(). string.Split() is much faster but Regex.Split() is more powerful.

`string.Split()` version:

```
        var parts = input.Split(new []{'"', '\''})
            .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
            .Select(p => p.Trim())
            .ToList();
```

`Regex.Split()`version:

```
        var input = "\"bcd ef\" a 'x y'";
        var parts = Regex.Split(input, "[\"']")
            .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
            .Select(p => p.Trim())
            .ToList();
```

As long as you want to split by single characters, the regex version is simply slower. So there's no reason to use it.

Docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split